# Nuxt default template generate static assets twice the size of Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

- Init project with `npx create-nuxt-app <my-project>`
- Generate static html for index.vue with `npm run generate`

The output require 170KB of js in 4 files:

[image]

***In Universal-production mode the same route is only 62.3 KB***

(I am using default build options.)

**Questions:**

- Is there any optimisation to turn the size close to the SSR output?
- Isn't the static output supposed to be smaller?

Comment: What is the question?

I guess that webpack adds a lot of minification in the production build to reduce package size

Answer (score 1):

*Answer from the discord thanks manniL*

**Both static and SSR have pretty the same size. My results were wrong.**

SSR output is automatically gzipped but static generated files aren't, you have to configure your CDN/hostinge service to enable it.

[image]

That's still pretty big compared to vuejs alone (~50KB minified), but i guess it's the expected size.